# expanding my linux mint partition to include unallocation partition

Tags: partition, gparted

Good morning from Australia.
Could someone please help me. I have researched this topic for days but nothing seems to exactly cover my particular question with the space that I have.
I am running Linux mint 20 and have recently unmounted and deleted my windows partition in Gparted, which left me with approx 152G of unallocated space, which I want to add/merge with my Linux partition. I am concerned I may do something wrong. Please keep it simple for this pensioner. Image of Gparted screen below which is where I'm at. TIA

[image: screenshot before resize]

**Edit:** Partitions after successful resize operation

[image: screenshot after resize]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot from a Linux Live USB/CD with GParted to be able to resize your root partition since it is currently in use (see the key symbol).
You can boot from your Linux Mint USB stick or download a [GParted Live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/download.php) ISO and write that to a thumbdrive.

Then start GParted, select "/dev/sda7 Linux Mint", right click on "Resize/Move" and resize the partition to take all
unallocated space and confirm the operation. If the result looks as desired, click the checkmark in the top bar to apply all operations.

Since you deleted Windows, you may also delete the leftover "Microsoft reserved partition" and use that space too.

Comment: Freddy- thank you for your answer. You said,

 "You can boot from your Linux Mint USB stick or download a GParted Live CD/USB ISO and write that to a thumbdrive."

So is that one or the other? I downloaded a live version of GParted to a USB. I don't have a Linux Mint on USB anymore. How do I start this version as I also have GParted on my laptop.

Comment: It's one or the other, most Linux Live versions I know come with GParted preinstalled.
You need to start GParted from a different device than your Mint installation.
The ISO version can be written directly to the USB: copy the ISO to your harddrive, find out the device name of the USB (`/dev/sdc` or `/dev/sdd` or ... with `dmesg`), then use that device name as target in the `dd` command.
See the instructions in the [manual](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php#linux-method-d). 
If you want to use a GUI tool, use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html).

Comment: Freddy, thank you, you're a champ. Its all done. For some reason the new screen shot of the resized partition went to the top of the page.